# Сборка jar под ant

Tags: ant, java, jar

Есть приложение на Свинге. Надо осбрать из него джарку. Вот код сборки:

```
<project name="TestProject" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <target name="compile">
        <delete dir="target"/>

        <mkdir dir="target"/>
        <mkdir dir="target/compiled"/>

        <copy todir="target/compiled">
            <fileset dir="./src">
                <include name="*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="./src">
                <include name="*.properties"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>

        <copy todir="target/compiled/model">
            <fileset dir="./src/model" />
        </copy>

        <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="target/compiled" debug="true">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <jar destfile="target/SW.jar" filesetmanifest="merge">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="run/RunApp"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="target/compiled" />

        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

При запуске выдает сообщение, что не может найти главный класс. И даже когда собрал автоматом из под Eclipse, то же самое. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="run/RunApp"/>
```

- вот здесь не верно. Верно будет что-то типа:

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="cav.Vam"/>
```

где cav - это пакет, а Vam - это главный класс.